# How to check how much CPU assigned to my VPS?

Tags: centos, cpu, vps

I have bought a VPS service that is claimed to give 4 cores wuth total 6GHz power. I have installed CentOS 8 on this VPS and want to check if I have that power of CPU or not?

This is the info I do get whit `lscpu` command:

```
Architecture:        x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):      32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:          Little Endian
CPU(s):              4
On-line CPU(s) list: 0-3
Thread(s) per core:  1
Core(s) per socket:  4
Socket(s):           1
NUMA node(s):        1
Vendor ID:           GenuineIntel
CPU family:          6
Model:               63
Model name:          Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz
Stepping:            2
CPU MHz:             3491.914
BogoMIPS:            6983.82
Hypervisor vendor:   KVM
Virtualization type: full
L1d cache:           32K
L1i cache:           32K
L2 cache:            4096K
L3 cache:            16384K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):   0-3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may count number of processors:

```
grep -c "Model name" /proc/cpuinfo
```

But you  have answer it in your question post

```
CPU(s): 4
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to know what capacity each core has?

Comment: @user3486308 You already posted it in your question `Model name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-1650 v3 @ 3.50GHz`

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way:

```
nproc
```

Sample output:

> 4

Comment: Thanks but I want to know what capacity each core has?

Comment: On a VPS your CPU "capacity" will be variable. Despite it not being shared hosting, the other machines on the physical machine *will* affect your available CPU capacity. So you can't determine it simply because you don't know the workload of other websites.